# Django subquery problem "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Tags: mysql, django-models, mysql-error-1242

I have three related models like

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,unique=False,null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']        

class County(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,unique=False,null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class District(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    county = models.ForeignKey(County,unique=False,null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

What I'd like to do is getting all the `Districts` for a specified city. 
I tried :

```
District.objects.all().filter(county = County.objects.all().filter(city=City.objects.filter(id=4)))
```

However, it gives error like `OperationalError: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')`

Can you give me any idea how I can achive this query in django ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're complicating things by doing them that way. You could get away with something along the lines of:

For a given instance `city` of the model `City`, you can get all `Districts` in this way:

`District.objects.filter(county__city=city)`

You may want to go through this section on the Django documentation called [Lookups that span relationships](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) as it explains how you can achieve similar lookup queries.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'll definitely go through that documentation.